# How to put multiple where statements into function on kdb+

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to write a function using kdb+ which will look at the list, and find the values that simply meet two conditions.

Let's call the list DR (for data range). And I want a function that will combine these two conditions
"DR where (DR mod 7) in 2"
and
"DR where (DR.dd) in 1"
I'm able to apply them one at a time but I really need to combine them into one function. I was hoping I could do this
"DR was (DR.dd mod 7) in 2 and DR where (DR.dd) in 1"
but this obviously didn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the `and` function to help with this, which is the same as `&`:

```
q)dr:.z.d+til 100
q)and
&
q)2=dr mod 7
10000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000100000010000001000000..
q)1=dr.dd
00000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000..
q)(1=dr.dd)&2=dr mod 7
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000..
q)dr where(1=dr.dd)&2=dr mod 7
2021.02.01 2021.03.01
```

Its necessary wrap the first part in brackets due to how kdb reads code from right to left. This format changes slightly when doing this in a where clause, the brackets arent needed due to how each where clause is parsed, that is each clause between the commas are parsed seperately. However it is essentially doing the same thing as the code above.

```
q)t:([]date:dr)
q)select from t where 1=date.dd,2=date mod 7
date
----------
2021.02.01
2021.03.01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using `min` to achieve similar results, like so:

```
DR where min(1=DR.dd;2=DR mod 7)
```